# Does not display in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

whats wrong with this code. Function accepts two numbers, add them and display result. But the result is not displayed at all. Please help

```
EditText edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display1);
num1 = Float.valueOf(edt1.getText().toString());

EditText edt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.display2);
num2 = Float.valueOf(edt2.getText().toString());
Button calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);

calculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View  v)
     { 
       result=num1+num2;
       TextView d3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.display3);
       d3.setText(Float.toString(result));              
     }
});
```

Comment: You should include your xml code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the  num1 = Float.valueOf(edt2.getText().toString()); into the onClick() method (same for num2).

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the value inside the EditTexts outside of the onClick listener.

And another note: It's a good practice, especially if things don't work as you would expect, to first check if you got the value you were expecting before trying to present it back.

Always check variables values. Ask yourself `Is this variable set correctly?`
This way you could really close in on the problem yourself. Here, for example:

```
public void onClick(View  v){ 
    Log.d("myApp","num1 is: "+num1);
    Log.d("myApp","num2 is: "+num2);
    result=num1+num2;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put:

getting num1 and num2 code in onClick

And You should not put this code in onClick:

```
TextView d3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.display3);
```

Put this after

```
 Button calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this inside on click

```
  num1 = Float.valueOf(edt1.getText().toString());
  num2 = Float.valueOf(edt2.getText().toString());
```

Also move this to `onCreate` declare TextView d3 as a class member

```
   d3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.display3);  // no need to initialize everytime on button click
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you initialize num1 and num2 in onCreate() method. so you cannot get anything. you have to get num1 and num2 value in onClick(View v). try this

```
public void onClick(View  v)
{ 
  num1 = Float.valueOf(edt1.getText().toString());
  num2 = Float.valueOf(edt2.getText().toString());
  result=num1+num2;
  TextView d3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.display3);
  d3.setText(Float.toString(result));             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this:

```
final EditText edt1      = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display1);
final EditText edt2      = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display2);
final Button   calculate = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.add);
final TextView d3        = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display3);

calculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View  v){ 

       int num1   = Float.valueOf(edt1.getText().toString());
       int num2   = Float.valueOf(edt2.getText().toString());

       float result = num1+num2;    

       d3.setText(Float.toString(result));              
    }
});
```